# Controlling content access by domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, domain-driven-design, multimedia

For a user generated content website, I want to give ability to my users to restrict on who can see the content.

Domain based restriction seems like a good choice( users can embed content content on their own site).

Any samples/suggestions/known gotchas on how we should implement domain restriction on content?

Our solution is developed on asp.net mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authorization scheme you would use is independent of whether you use DDD or not.

You would probably use a Role-based authorization scheme. Every item of content then comes with an Access Control List (ACL), which is basically a list of roles and their rights -- for instance, all users who are in the FoodAuthors group can modify a particular piece of content, and all users in the FoodReaders group can only read it. Users who are in neither group/role have no access to the content.

Furthermore, you can divide up your content into categories (or "channels", whatever term you prefer), and organize these categories/channels in a tree structure. Then you can put ACLs on the categories/channels rather than on the content itself. So, an article on whole foods would be put in the /Health/Food channel, for instance, and the FoodReaders group would get read access to all content in that channel.